# Error 404 in deployig of my first Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

This is my first Servlet, I do whatever books says, But got `404` Error.

I use `Tomcat 7.0.56` and `Windows 7` , I have been set all variable environments.

Here is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/FirstServlet/PersonalServlet")
public class PersonalServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws  IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/HTML");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD>");
    out.println("<TITLE>Simple Servlet</TITLE>");
    out.println("</HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("<BR><BR><BR>");

    String clientName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    out.println("<H1> A Simple Servlet for ");
    out.println(clientName + "</H1></CENTER>");
    out.println("</BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");
    out.flush();
    }
}
```

This is my `Hello.html` in `C:\tomcat\webapps\FirstServlet\Hello.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=GET action="PersonalServlet">
    Enter Your first name:

    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my `web.xml` in `C:\tomcat\webapps\FirstServlet\WEB-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee "
xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd "
version="3.0">

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PersonalServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>PersonalServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>


   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PersonalServlet/servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/PersonalServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My tomcat has configure successfully,

But when i try  `http://127.0.0.1:8080/FirstServlet/PersonalServlet`

Or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/FirstServlet/`

I got this Error.

I put class of servlet in `C:\tomcat\webapps\FirstServlet\WEB-INF\classes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to use xml configuration if you use @WebServlet annotation. In that case configuration from web.xml overwrites annotation configuration.
2. So, now, when configuration from web.xml is used, you should access you servlet by /PersonalServlet URL, that you provided in url-pattern.
3. Also, you should provide fully-qualified name in servlet-class element.

Comment: I want to use `@WebServlet("/FirstServlet/PersonalServlet")` because it is simple, should i delete `web.xml` entirely, Or just remove `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags?

Comment: @user3808021 You could remove it entirely if you don't need it for anything else. Otherwise - remove tags, yes.

Comment: Sorry, What is this mean: `@WebServlet("/PersonalServlet")` ?

Comment: @user3808021 This means "invoke this class service() method on any request, which url path matches pattern provided in quotes". As far as you extend HttpServlet you could override doGet method that would be called in service method of parent class if request http method is GET.

Answer (score 0):

Give fully-qualified class name here..

Inside web.xml

```
<servlet-class>**Fully qualified class name**</servlet-class>
```

Why are you using both xml and Annotation, remove

```
 @WebServlet("/FirstServlet/PersonalServlet")
```

from your class..

Comment: fully qualified class name.. Package name and class name. eg if you have your class placed in a package com.test.servlet then the above syntax will be <servlet-class>com.test.servlet.PersonalServlet </servlet-class>

Comment: I want to use `@WebServlet("/FirstServlet/PersonalServlet") ` because it is simple, should i delete `web.xml` entirely, Or just remove `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping> tags?

Comment: remove the web.xml then the annotation becomes @WebServlet(name="PersonalServlet", urlPatterns={"/PersonalServlet"})

Answer (score -1):

This is how it should look like:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PersonalServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>PersonalServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PersonalServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PersonalServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```